# Cannot give struct as a type to create a 2D array of structs

Tags: rust

I'm attempting to create a simple, fixed-size 2D array of Node structs with size [MAX_X, MAX_Y]. This:

```
let mut map = [[Node; MAX_X as usize]; MAX_Y as usize];

struct Node {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}
```

gives the error message:

```
main.rs:12:21: 12:25 error: `Node` is a struct variant name, but this expression uses it like a function name [E0423]
main.rs:12     let mut map = [[Node; MAX_X as usize]; MAX_Y as usize];
                               ^~~~
main.rs:12:21: 12:25 help: did you mean to write: `Node { /* fields */ }`?
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is vaguely akin to saying `let mut i = i32;`; it doesn't make any sense because you're trying to assign a type to a variable.  You need to actually provide a *value*, not a type.

However, even that won't work because, given the definition above, `Node` isn't `Copy`, so the compiler can't construct the array anyway.

Here's something that will work, but first, a few notes:

- Note that this is constructing the array on the stack.  If you make it too big, you run the risk of overflowing the stack and crashing.
- `MAX_X` and `MAX_Y` *must* be constants; they cannot be variables.  Your casting of them (and lack of a complete example) makes me worry that you might be using variables..

```rust
fn main() {
    #[derive(Copy, Clone)]
    struct Node {
        x: i32,
        y: i32,
    }

    const MAX_X: usize = 8;
    const MAX_Y: usize = 16;

    let mut map = [[Node { x: 0, y: 0 }; MAX_X]; MAX_Y];
}
```

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. MAX_X and MAX_Y are constants, yes. Is it the Rustic way in general to prefer allocating default structures, then filling them with proper values later?

Comment: @descent: That's hugely subjective and depends on the specific case.  Personally, I avoid having "dummy" values lying around, purely so I don't have to keep track of whether I've replaced them or not.

Answer (score 1):

> `let mut map = [[Node; MAX_X as usize]; MAX_Y as usize];`

There are 2 issues

- In rust `:` is used to define the variable type and `=` to define its value. In your case you used `=` to define a type
- All variables need to be initialized (memory should be allocated).

  - If `MAX_X` and `MAX_Y` values are dynamic then you don't have a choice but use `Vec<_>` instead of fixed-sized array
  - If `MAX_X` and `MAX_Y` are constants then you can statically initialize `map` like this (note that data type is inferred): `let mut map = [[Node {x:0, y:0}, Node {x:0, y:0}, Node {x:0, y:0}], [Node {x:0, y:0}, Node {x:0, y:0}, Node {x:0, y:0}], [Node {x:0, y:0}, Node {x:0, y:0}, Node {x:0, y:0}]]`